# How do I include a Module into another Module (Refactor AASM code and custom states into Module)

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor a superfat model which has quite a few lines of ActsAsStateMachine code related to the states and transitions, and I was hoping to refactor this to a module call CallStates.

```
#in lib/CallStates.rb
module CallStates
    module ClassMethods
        aasm_column :status
        aasm_state :state1
        aasm_state :state2
        aasm_state :state3
    end

    def self.included(base)
        base.send(:include, AASM)
        base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end
end
```

And then in the model

```
include CallStates
```

My question concerns how to include Module behavior into a Module such that a single Module can be included into the model.  I've tried class_eval do as well to no avail.  Thanks for any insightful thoughts you have on the matter.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662722/extending-a-ruby-module-in-another-module-including-the-module-methods

Answer (score 53):

You can't include one module in another exactly, but you can tell a module to include other modules in the class into which it's included:

```
module Bmodule
  def greet
    puts 'hello world'
  end
end

module Amodule
  def self.included klass
    klass.class_eval do
      include Bmodule
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  include Amodule
end

MyClass.new.greet # => hello world
```

It's best to only do this if Bmodule is actually data that is necessary for Amodule to function, otherwise it can lead to confusion because it's not explicitly included in MyClass.

Comment: This I was able to get to work, although it makes for a huge block wthin klass.class_eval.  Now the constant which I was easily able do define in the base class (in a hash assignment MYCONST = {:key1 => 'value1', :key2 => 'value2' } is throwing a SyntaxError - "dynamic constant assignment" ... do I have to do some sort of base.const_set in this case?

Comment: You don't have to do anything special to get this to work, but you should make sure that you aren't setting the value of MYCONST more than once - that is what causes the warning you are seeing.  Make sure you aren't using any meta-programming or eval statements to set MYCONST as well, because these will cause the same issue.

Answer (score 28):

You include a module into another module by ... including a module into another module, of course!

```
module Bmodule
  def greet
    puts 'hello world'
  end
end

module Amodule
  include Bmodule
end

class MyClass
  include Amodule
end

MyClass.new.greet # => hello world
```

Comment: Sure - I get that.  With including AASM into the 'Amodule' wasn't giving me the ability to call subsequent methods that AASM makes available, so I was under the impression that somehow I had to rewrite the AASM methods to be relevant to the class that ultimately implements these states.

Comment: I have noticed, though, that if you're trying to include custom modules into core modules, you need to tell classes to re-include those modules anyway.

E.g. I had a `module Trackable` (mine) that I wanted to include in `module Enumerable` (core) so I didn't have to explicitly include it in all of its including classes (e.g. `Array`, `Range`, `Enumerator` and `CSV::Table`); but I still had to say `class Array; include Enumerable; end` for it to work.

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, include classes for all included mixins are created when the mixin is included in the class. Adding a mixin after that will not create a new include class. Otherwise Ruby would have keep track of every class the mixin has ever been included in and update them whenever you include a new mixin. Or worse, if you were to get rid of include classes altogether, it would have to linearize the entire mixin chain on *every* method call.

Answer (score 23):

### Rails

For Rails, you'll want to do something like this:

**module_b.rb**

```
module ModuleB
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include ModuleA
  end
end
```

**my_model.rb**

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ModuleB

end
```

`ModuleA` is being included in `ModuleB`, which is then included in `MyModel` class.

Answer (score 10):

I like this syntax the best:

```
module Bmodule
  def greet
    puts 'hello world'
  end
end

module Amodule
  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.send :include, Bmodule
  end
end

class MyClass
  include Amodule
end

MyClass.new.greet # => hello world
```