# Extend module inside another module

Tags: ruby

I want to invoke method `a` from method of module `B`. How can I do it? I don't want to specify `A::a` every time.

```
module A
  def self.a
    "a"
  end
end

module B
  extend A

  def self.b
    a
  end
end

p B::b  # => undefined local variable or method `a' for B:Module
```

Comment: You're extending A, but `a` is a class method on `A` if you had `def a` and not `def self.a` it would work as expected, otherwise use `include` instead of `extend`

Comment: Do you need really need `A::a` to be a class method?

Comment: @DaveNewton I think, yes

Comment: @AndreyBotalov If it doesn't, then use the normal `extends` mechanism as in quandary's answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton I meant `A::a` should be module method. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663029/841064) a method to solve it but it doesn't look good to me:

```
module A 
  module ClassMethods
    def a
      puts "a"
    end
  end
  extend ClassMethods
  def self.included( other )
    other.extend( ClassMethods )
  end
end

module B
  include A

  def self.b
    a
  end
end

p B::b  # => "a"
```

Answer (score 7):

When using `extend` or `include`, Ruby will only mixin the instance methods. Extend will mix them in as class methods, but it won't mix in the class methods. Therefore, an easy solution to your query:

```
module A
  def a  ## Change to instance
    "a"
  end
end

module B
  extend A

  def self.b
    a
  end
end

p B::b #=> "a"
p B.b  #=> "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this "weird" code:

```
module A
  def self.a
    "a"
  end
end

module B
  extend A

  def self.method_missing(name, *args)
    if name =~ /a/
        A::a *args
    else
        raise "MethodMissed: #{name}"
    end
  end

  def self.b
    a
  end
end

p B::b
```