# Overwrite class method from another module

Tags: ruby, module

I want to modify the existing module `A` from a library:

```
module A
  class << self
    def foo
      bar('Baz')
    end

    private

    def bar(val)
      val.upcase
    end
  end
end

A.foo
=> "BAZ"

module B
  extend A

  def self.bar(val)
    val.downcase
  end
end

B.foo            # hoping for 'baz', but instead:
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for B:Module
```

Is there a way to re-use method `.foo` from `A` and only modify method `.bar`?

Comment: If you are curious, this is the module I want to re-use: https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/v0.18.0/lib/grape/error_formatter/json.rb

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662722/extending-a-ruby-module-in-another-module-including-the-module-methods ?

Comment: Very interesting question!

Comment: @Deradon: not a real duplicate. In the other question the author owns also the base module. Here the base module resides in a public library. Only one of the answers considers that might not always be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `A` declared as above, the following code would do:

```
▶ B = A.clone
#⇒ B
▶ (class << B; self; end).send :define_method, :bar do |val|
  val.downcase
end
▶ A.foo
#⇒ "BAZ"
▶ B.foo
#⇒ "baz"
```

There probably should be less tricky way, but I can’t yet figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

`extend A` doesn't work, because `foo` and `bar` are no instance methods of `A`, but of `A`'s singleton class. To re-use those methods, you have to either create a copy of `A` as mudasobwa described, or you can use a refinement of `A`'s singleton class like this:

```
module B
  extend(refine(A.singleton_class) do
    def bar(val)
      val.downcase
    end
  end)
end

B.foo # => "baz"
```

You cannot use `extend A.singleton_class` as `extend` doesn't accept a class as argument. `refine` returns a module which is exactly what's needed.

Comment: I've never though about [Module#refine](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-refine) being used for this purpose. Great answer!

Comment: This is great, upvoted. First application of `refine` I saw that it really meaningful.

Comment: Note that while Refinements are part of Ruby, they are not implemented in all Ruby implementations. Most notably, the Rubinius developers are philosophically opposed to the idea of Refinements, and thus will never implement them. (One could argue whether an implementation that willfully ignores a feature of Ruby can be called a "Ruby implementation" at all.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this change in the Ruby code has made this solution invalid: http://mla.n-z.jp/~w3ml/w3ml.cgi/ruby-changes/msg/46511. This applies to Ruby versions >= 2.3.5 and >= 2.4.2. The error message then is `ArgumentError: refinement module is not allowed`.